# D Lang. Упаковать DLL в EXE

Tags: dll, resources, d

Здравствуйте. Вопрос по std.net.curl.
Класс использует динамическую библиотеку libcurl.dll, пытается ее подгрузить из системных папок и из папки с исполняемым EXE. 
Вопрос заключается в следующем, как можно упаковать данную библиотеку в сам exe. И еще один вопрос, как из программного кода получить доступ к ресурсам, к примеру к sometext.txt на скриншоте.

[image: пример одного из ресурсов]

Comment: Статическая линковка? Использование ресурсов?